# "undefined" getting output in event loop, why?

Tags: javascript

I have been reading [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) great article that explains the event loop.

Inside that article there is this code that illustrate how the messages are queued and processed:

```js
function f() {
  console.log("foo");
  setTimeout(g, 0);
  console.log("baz");
  h();
}

function g() {
  console.log("bar");
}

function h() {
  console.log("blix");
}

f();
```

This will print in console (Chrome) the following:
foo, baz, blix, **undefined**, bar.

I think I understand what is going on here, but I do not understand where is this **undefined** coming from?

Comment: The undefined is coming from the result of a function call, it is returning undefined and chrome is just printing it.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`undefined` is the return value of `f()`, which you'll see if you're executing this on an interactive console which automatically prints the value of the last executed expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` value is the result of the statement `f()`. Each statement in javascript has a value as an expression; functions without explicit return statement basically return `undefined`.

The Chrome console always prints out the value of the last executed statement, which is the result of `f()` in this case.

It's confusing that **bar** is printed out later (i.e. after `f()` returns); but that is caused by the timeout.